# How to edit master in order to create dev and prevent conflict during merge from dev to master?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-merge, rebase

I have a `master` branch.

I need to delete `CHANGELOG.md` **and** update the `version` in `package.json` using value `0.0.0-development` and create a `dev` branch of it.

I then need to be able to do change using `dev` branch, and proceed to a merge to `master` without having to resolve the conflict for `CHANGELOG.md` and `package.json` locally.

This is how I currently create my `dev` branch and everyone who will want to start commiting into `dev` will need to resolve conflict locally when merging to `master`:

```
  git fetch origin master
  git checkout origin/master
  git pull origin master
  git checkout -b dev
  cat package.json | jq '.version = 0.0.0-development' > package.json.tmp$$
  mv package.json.tmp$$ package.json
  rm CHANGELOG.md
  git add package.json
  git add CHANGELOG.md
  git commit -n -m 'build(dev): preparing dev branch'
  git push origin dev
```

How can I do ?

Comment: you mean, your master branch should still have `CHANGELOG.md` and the original version in `package.json`, but your dev branch will *not* have `CHANGELOG.md` and will have a different version in `package.json` than master?

Comment: Yes basically, it is the same, I have added a snippet to demonstrate how I am having this.

Comment: I don't think you can change the fact that you will have a merge conflict since the trees are different. However, you can use [`git rerere`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere). So basically, upon doing the merge and getting the conflict, you fix it manually one time, then on each subsequent merge, rerere will run automatically for any merge. See [here](https://hackernoon.com/fix-conflicts-only-once-with-git-rerere-7d116b2cec67)

Comment: Thanks for `git rerere` and article, I feel this is a too much complicated solution and we will stick to the manual merge unless a simple solution exist for it.

Comment: Maybe it seems intimidating -- it really isn't. You just enable a config option in `.gitconfig` and then proceed as normal, except in the background, git will be recording the resolutions. This is exactly the use case for `git rerere`.

Comment: It seems even more intimidating as I have no experience with it, and the current use case imply `Gitlab-CI` creating within script a GitHub repo and configuring it (non interactive). Also, it is a step all our repo can have so a wide solution would be much appreciated and I am not familiare at all with `git rerere`

Answer (score 0):

A simpler sequence of commands would be:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout -b dev
# modify/add your files
git commit -m "prepare dev"
git push -u origin dev
```

As long as the `CHANGELOG.md`/`package.json` files don't change in `master`, a subsequent merge from `dev` to `master` won't trigger any conflict.